# How to handle error thown in RxJava chain

Tags: java, rx-java

I am trying to execute following code

```
 testRepository
                .exists(data)
                .flatMap(x -> {
                    if (x==null) {
                        return Observable.error(new Exception("Error"));
                    }
                    return Observable.just(x);
                })
                .flatMap(x -> testRepository.create(x))
                .flatMap(x -> {
                    return Observable.just(x);
                });
```

This code works when no error is thrown in first map. But in case when error is thrown it just hangs.
What is wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please describe what `exists()` method does, and add your subscriber code as well?

Comment: It check for existence and returns an observable with content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't declared error properly, you shouldn't perform explicit converting to error observable via flatMap, because in case positive state you create new observable for each item and combine them after all.

You may just use

```
.doOnNext(x -> {
    if (x == null) throw new IllegalStateException("null item error");
})
```

And this exception will interrupt stream and will be properly handled in `onError` callback of subscription.

Last instruction also doesn't make sense, because you convert each element to a single item observable and then combine them back to a similar stream.

Ps: also it needs to be called `.subscribe` somewhere, but i think it is meant.

Comment: Last flat map is just for demonstration.

Comment: Yep, subscribe is there.

Comment: I see. So try it)

Comment: @AshwaniK So what was the cause of that hanging? Apparently it is not what Beloo suggested. Your original code was not optimal but OK.

Comment: Yep, the issue was with my subscriber as I was using this with vertx, Onerror the vertx context was not closed

Comment: @AshwaniK That's why I was asking you to show your subscriber :)

Comment: @YaroslavStavnichiy: Actually just trying out RxJava. Did not think that subscriber can be a problem too :P